# Spigot - Cast String to Material - Java

Tags: java, string, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to cast a String to a `Material` by doing this:

```
for (Material ma : Material.values()) {
    if (String.valueOf(ma.getId()).equals(args[0]) || ma.name().equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])) {
    }
}
```

If `args[0]` is a String like `2` or `grass` it works very well, but how can I cast for example `41:2` to `Material`?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: I don't know what a `Material` is in Spigot, but I think the first question is what you expect the String `"41:2"` to become. Is that a range of values? Is the '2' a modifier on the material?

Comment: In Spigot/Minecraft a `Material` has an ID and a Name. Grass has the ID `2` and the Name `grass` or `minecraft:grass`. When I have the `Material`, I want to change the Type of a Block at a given `Location`. Like this: `Location.getBlock().setType(Material);` @soong

Comment: Okay, so what does the `41` mean in that? What specifically should `41:2` come out to mean? Either 41 or 2?

Comment: 41:x are Slab's, so that are half Blocks and I think 41:2 is a Stone Slab. But 41:2 is just a example. It could also be 89:5 or 112:4. @soong

Comment: It sounds like you need to invest some time into making a function that takes one of those string inputs and returns just the `Material` part of that. If `x:y` is the only possible pattern other than the two you already check for, then something involving `String.split()` should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the notation you're describing which uses two magic values (the type ID and data value) separated by a colon to specify the certain "type" of a block, you'll need to split the string and set the two values separately. There might be a nicer way to convert the magic value data byte using the `MaterialData` class, but it's probably still easier to use the direct and deprecated method of `block.setData(byte data)`. So if `args[0]` contains a colon, split it and parse the two numbers. Something along the lines of this could work for you:

```
if (arguments[0].contains(":")) { // If the first argument contains colons
    String[] parts = arguments[0].split(":"); // Split the string at all colon characters
    int typeId; // The type ID
    try {
        typeId = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // Parse from the first string part
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { // If the string is not an integer
        sender.sendMessage("The type ID has to be a number!"); // Tell the CommandSender
        return false;
    }
    byte data; // The data value
    try {
        data = Byte.parseByte(parts[1]); // Parse from the second string part
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        sender.sendMessage("The data value has to be a byte!");
        return false;
    }

    Material material = Material.getMaterial(typeId); // Material will be null if the typeId is invalid!

    // Get the block whose type ID and data value you want to change

    if (material != null) {
        block.setType(material);
        block.setData(data); // Deprecated method
    } else {
        sender.sendMessage("Invalid material ID!");
    }

}
```